# Separate directory for tables

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a subdirectory for all of my tables and use it in a similar way to `\graphicspath`. I have a lot of tables and don't want to see them in my main text.

Comment: We are going to need some more detail here: tables are (normally) just part of the source.

Comment: You probably can use `\input` command to externalize your table

Comment: one \input for each table?

Comment: @NicolásSacco yes

Comment: Thank you Roman, what if I want to have all my tables in the same place?

Comment: Then you can define a command for each table - all in the "same_place.tex" file, `\input` it, and just call the appropriate command  when needed.

Comment: Can you give me an easy example?

Comment: @NicolásSacco: Sorry, I have to remark that the kind of your questions is often very broad or unclear. Basically no MWE, only confusing comments or additional requests, but you've neither upvoted the answers to your questions nor accepted (some) of the answers (No, I am not one of the users who answered one of your questions.) -- In my point of view this disrespecting the efforts of the community here :-(

Comment: Im sorry Christian, im very new in the community and actually its very confusing to me how it works. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have tables in separate file(s) in a subdirectory, you can do something like this:

- make a subdirectory (say "tables")
- create a tex file in that subdirectory containing new commands with the table definitions, say the file "chapter1tables.tex" containing:

  ```
  \newcommand*\TableOneOne{%
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 1 & a \\ 
        \hline 2 & b \\ 
        \hline 
      \end{tabular}
  }
  ```
- `input` the "chapter1tables.tex" file(s) in your main tex file
- call your defined commands for the tables when needed:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \input{tables/chapter1tables}

   \begin{document}
     Here comes the table: 

     \TableOneOne
   \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 8):

Here is something similar to `\includegraphics` and `\graphicspath`. If `\tablepath` isn't defined the command tries to include the filename given as argument from the current directory.

If `\tablepath` is defined, it will look if the file exists there, otherwise it will try to use the local directory (again)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tablepath}{mytables}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includetable}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{tablepath}{%
    \InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}%
  }{%
    \InputIfFileExists{\tablepath/#1}{}{\InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}}%
  }
}
\makeatother    



\begin{document}

\includetable{tablea}

\includetable{tableb}



\end{document}
```

Here are the definitions of `tablea` and `tableb`:

`tablea.tex`

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
A & B \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

`tableb.tex`  -- I've stored this in my `mytables` directory.

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
C & D \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please note: This is a quick hack, nothing fully reliable, due lack of time