# Default searching path for VerbatimInput in fancyvrb package

Tags: fancyvrb

I write/collect some codes (e.g., C, R or Matlab) in a subdirectory named, say, **myCodes**.  Then I want to use *VerbatimInput* from **usepackage{fancyvrb}** to list the codes in some absolute path way. I know the *graphicspath* from **usepackage{graphicx}** can do this work for figures. How the same issue can be solved for codes? My .tex file reads

```
\documentclass{article}
% ================= figure================ 
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{{./myFigs/}}
% ================= code================ 
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
%\codespath{{./myCodes/}} %??????

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput[label=hello.c]{myCodes/hello.c} 
%\VerbatimInput[label=hello.c]{hello.c} %??????

\end{document}
```

And my sample C code **hello.c** reads

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```

According to [Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284347/separate-directory-for-tables), I mimic that as

```
    %=========================================
    \newcommand{\codepath}{myCodes}
    %-----------------------------------------
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\includecode}[1]{%
    \@ifundefined{codepath}{%
        \InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}%
    }{%
        \InputIfFileExists{\codepath/#1}{}{\InputIfFileExists{#1}{}{}}%
    }
    }
    \makeatother
```

Then I use

```
  \VerbatimInput[label=hello.c]{\includecode{hello.c}}
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Implementing path prefixes is something really difficult. Even graphicspath is not perfect.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  There is no default mechanism set-up for this.  The graphicspath code is fairly complicated, but could be emulated.  Do you need just one directory or a whole list?

Comment: Tks anyway@ TeXnician@ Andrew Swann